# ucrtbase.DLL crashed with Exception Code: 40000015

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I installed this wheel https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.9.0/py36/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl on windows 7 32 bits.

I ran some code, first it throw some warning that your cpu support AVX and then it crash by this error

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
Application Name: python.exe 
Application Version: 3.6.8150.1013 
Application Timestamp: 5c201b63 
Fault Module Name: ucrtbase.DLL 
Fault Module Version: 10.0.14393.2990 
Fault Module Timestamp: 5caeb859 
Exception Code: 40000015 
Exception Offset: 000884da 
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
Locale ID: 1033 
Additional Information 1: f419 
Additional Information 2: f419a63a49a2df57b723a80593a88e82 
Additional Information 3: e2c1 
Additional Information 4: e2c181b5a2bed9dd090d71f8ac7769de

What is the problem? 
How I should fix it?

Tnx

Although I test the code on virtual machine with win7 32 bits, and it's just work fine, but on the actual pc with win7 32 bits it throws the error.

I installed same windows edition, same python version, same msvc, same update, everything is equal but one of them is on virtual machine and the other one is a real pc. How I could get the actual problem? The error says that ucrtbase.dll crashed but I switched this dll between the two os, the first one worked fine even with the crashed dll, but the other one still throws the error, so I think the problem is some where else, but how I could find the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

I spent days trying everything under the sun. It turned out this fixes it for some reason:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```